# User Auth Context returns empty object in react with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-context

I am trying to use Context API for user authentication to Firebase from my React app. I wrote the code for the context provider in AuthContext.js which includes all the auth functions. It successfully runs and also provides all the `currentuser` info.

AuthContext.js

```
const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }
  function googleSignIn() {
    const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
      console.log("Auth", currentuser);
      setUser(currentuser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, logIn, signUp, logOut, googleSignIn }}
    >
      {children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  return useContext(userAuthContext);
}
```

I have also wrapped the App component in `UserAuthContextProvider`. But when I try to use it in other components like Homepage, it returns an empty object for `user`. I did a lot of research finding the solution but couldn't really find where the problem lies.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <UserAuthContextProvider>
      <div className="app">
        <div className="navbar">
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div className="main">
          <Layout>
            <div className="header">
              <Title level={2} style={{ margin: "0px" }}>
                Welcome
              </Title>
              <Text style={{ margin: "0px", color: "grey" }}>
                Here's what's happening in the crypto world
              </Text>
            </div>
            <div
              className="
        routes"
            >
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
                <Route exact path="/exchanges" element={<Exchanges />} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/cryptocurrencies"
                  element={<Cryptocurrencies />}
                />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/crypto/:coinId"
                  element={<CryptoDetails />}
                />
                <Route exact path="/news" element={<News />} />
                <Route exact path="/watchlist" element={<Watchlist />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </Layout>

          <div className="footer">
            <Typography.Title
              level={5}
              style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}
            >
              Cryptocon <br />© All rights reserved
            </Typography.Title>
            <Space split={<Divider type="vertical" />}>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              <Link to="/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
              <Link to="/news">News</Link>
            </Space>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </UserAuthContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Homepage.jsx

```
  const { user } = useUserAuth();
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery(10);
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;

  if (isFetching) return <Loader />;
  -> console.log("The user is: " + user);

  return (
    <>
    ...
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hmmmm try wrapping the provider on the parent before declaring ```<App/>``` So ```<Provider><App/></Provider>```